# Why isn't Celery starting up?

Tags: django, celery

I have a Django app, which I've configured to use Celery. It works fine using the dev settings from the tutorial. Now I'm trying to get it working with a daemonized server.

I have Celery installed in a virtualenv, and am starting it (from the project's root directory) as follows:

```
celery multi restart worker1 --app=project.celeryapp -B --logfile=/tmp/celery.log --pidfile=/tmp/celery.pid
```

This produces the following output:

```
celery multi v3.1.18 (Cipater)
> worker1@ip-10-0-0-6: DOWN
> Restarting node worker1@ip-10-0-0-6: OK
```

So far so good, but the worker doesn't show up in `ps aux`, there is no pidfile, and the log is empty (but has been created).

Rerunning the command produces the same output (the worker starts DOWN). Increasing the log level still doesn't result in any log statements. No errors are thrown. How can I find out what's going on?

Comment: try using `celery worker...` instead of `celery multi...` and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `celery worker...` instead of `celery multi...` - since it does not daemonize it is easier to see error messages etc.

On a related note, from experience I would recommend using [supervisord](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/3.1/extra/supervisord/) to spawn `celery worker` processes instead of using `multi` at all.